# Time to display animation

Tags: iphone

How much time in seconds will it take to display an animation if you have 60 images using UIImageView class for property animationDuration

please answer this i am unable to respond it.....

good answer will get at least 4 up votes from all my friend group
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According Apple's reference:

> **animationDuration**
>
> The time duration is
> measured in seconds. The default value
> of this property is equal to the
> number of images multiplied by 1/30th
> of a second. Thus, if you had 30
> images, the value would be 1 second.

Thus with 60 images, if you don't set `animationDuration`, it will be 2 seconds.

When you set a custom value (say `n` seconds) for this property, it corresponds to the animation total duration (each image will be displayed during `n/60` seconds).

Answer (score 4):

That depends upon the time you have set in animationDuration.

Say for example

```
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image1,image2,......image60, nil];
myImage.animationImages = myImages;
myImage.animationDuration = 0.5;
myImage.animationRepeatCount = 1; // 0 = loops forever 
[myImage startAnimating];
```

This animation is gonna take numberOfImages*animationDuration (i.e. 60*0.5=30 seconds)

Hope its clear now....

hAPPY iCODING...

Comment: good ans but not accurat...........but good work ....i learn something....keep answering......+2